# Determining which PHP stdclass object occurs most often in an array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I have the following array of PHP stdclass objects (actually mine has hundreds of indices, but the goal is the same) and I am having trouble finding the most efficient way to determine programmatically with PHP which stdclass object occurs most often in the array.

If, for example, the standard class object at index 0 occurred most often (which obviously it does not), then I would like to echo out "1 , 1024" or something similar.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 1024
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 4096
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 6144
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 6144
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 6144
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 6144
        )

    [11] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 8192
        )

    [12] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 8192
        )

    [13] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 8192
        )

    [14] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => 8
            [b] => 8192
        )
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What was your approach?

Comment: And what do you mean by "which stdclass object occurs most often in the array"? Each object is an instance. Do you mean "objects with same a,b-pairs"?

Comment: As mentioned in the first comment, what has been your approach so far?

Comment: My current solution was similar to slashingweapon's, but less elegant. I was looping through and creating separate arrays for each object type and comparing their sizes. It worked but I felt it was sloppy. Also with hundreds of indices in some of the arrays I'm working with, I knew it was too slow.

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel Yes, I mean objects with the same a,b-pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I didn't go with either answer, specifically, they were both very helpful in helping me come up with this solution.

```
$x = array();
$count = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myArray); $i++) {
    if ($myArray[$i]->a != $myArray[$i - 1]->a 
        && $myArray[$i]->b != $myArray[$i - 1]->b) {
        $count = 0;
    }

    $x[$myArray[$i]->a . '|' . $myArray[$i]->b] = ++$count;
}

print_r($x);
```

Which results in the following output.

```
Array
(
    [1|1024] => 1
    [4|4096] => 5
    [4|6144] => 3
    [8|6144] => 2
    [8|8192] => 4
)
```

Then just grab the largest value from that array.

Answer (score 0):

Search all registers, storing the [a] ocurrences in an array/map and sort by count?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need something like this right? I think that is pretty fast. If you need check instances of the same object or similar you can generate the key with spl_object_hash function instead of concatenate the values as i do.

```
$foo = (object)['a' => 0, 'b' => 1024];
$bar = (object)['a' => 4, 'b' => 4096];
$qux = (object)['a' => 8, 'b' => 6144];

$array = [];
foreach(range(1, 1024) as $i) $array[] = $foo;
foreach(range(1, 4096) as $i) $array[] = $bar;
foreach(range(1, 6144) as $i) $array[] = $qux;

$result = [];
array_walk($array, function($obj) use (&$result) {
    $key = implode('|', get_object_vars($obj));
    if ( isset($result[$key]) ) $result[$key]++;
    else $result[$key] = 1;
});

arsort($result);
print_r($result);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [8|6144] => 6144
    [4|4096] => 4096
    [0|1024] => 1024
)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the `==` operator will tell you [if objects are equal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php).  So you can just loop through each item in the array, and build another array that keeps track of how often each value is encountered.  Then you'll need to sort the resulting array by count, so you know which object occurred most often.

```
$orig = array(
    (object)array('a'=>3, 'b'=>'4096'),
    (object)array('a'=>2, 'b'=>'2048'),
    (object)array('a'=>2, 'b'=>'2048'),
    (object)array('a'=>1, 'b'=>'1024'),
    (object)array('a'=>1, 'b'=>'1024'),
    (object)array('a'=>2, 'b'=>'2048'),
    (object)array('a'=>1, 'b'=>'1024'),
    (object)array('a'=>2, 'b'=>'2048'),
);

$countArray = array();

foreach($orig as $obj) {
    $didCount = false;
    foreach($countArray as $counted) {
        if ($counted->value == $obj) {
            $counted->count++;
            // if we found a match, record that fact and 
            // break out of this loop early.
            $didCount = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // If no match was found, then this is the first time 
    // we've seen this particular value
    if (!$didCount)
        $countArray[] = (object)array(
            'count' => 1,
            'value' => $obj,
        );
}

// To find the most frequent item, best way is to 
// sort $countArray by count.
usort($countArray, function($left, $right) {
    return $right->count - $left->count ;
});

print_r($countArray[0]);
```